# How to present a self certification on a CV or LinkedIn?

Tags: resume, united-kingdom

Recently I applied for a job that required a certificate in six-sigma, which I don't have. In my application, I argued I had all of the relevant experience (8 years') to be able to do the job.

I considered getting a six-sigma qualification, but it typically costs thousands of pounds, which i can't afford. Also, because there is no official six-sigma organisation offering certification, then I don't think the piece of paper is worth much.

After researching it, I've found that you can confer your own certification in six-sigma (after all, there is no official certifying body or body of knowledge).

So, my question is, how do I present this on my CV?

Comment: You should ask the company which six-sigma cert they accept. If your self-conferred cert does not ring a bell, they'll ask you what that cert of yours is and what to do to get it. Once they find out that your cert is self-conferred, all bets are off. If they are requiring a cert, it's a pretty good bet that they'll check on that cert and how you got it if you cite it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had experience with a project or a company that practiced six-sigma, I would say iffy but okay. Because it appears that you have neither training nor experience in six-sigma, just don't do it. You'll just upset your interviewers when they ask for details of your six-sigma experience.

Comment: +1 Given the valid points about the process, I don't think this unethical but it is somewhat misleading and you're going to wind up looking somewhat foolish. If they're interested it won't matter that you don't have it - if it's a big thing for them then they aren't going to be impressed by you making it up.